# Fullscreen image preview doesn't resize vertically

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple system to preview images on my website. The preview opens in a fullscreen view but the image should resize both horizontally and vertically. It does resize horizontally but it fails completely when I am trying to resize it vertically.

Here's the fiddle:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etekiller/rq53fvur/1/)

I'd appreciate some help with this. Vertical resizing seems to work when I give `fullscreenImageContainer` 100% height. The problem is that then the close button won't be located at the top right of the image.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 properties you need to apply / tweak. `max-width`, `max-height`, `width` and `height`

1. `width: auto;` adjusts the width to maintain the original aspect ratio - i.e. no stretching
2. `height: auto;` adjusts the width to maintain the original aspect ratio
3. `max-width: 90vw;` ensures that the object or preview `div` will never exceed 90% of the screen width.
4. `max-height: 90vh;` ensures that the object or preview `div` will never exceed 90% of the screen height.

With these four **combined,** the object will **always** be fully in view and you will not need to scroll the screen.

**Working example:** 
(open in full screen and try to resize vertically or horizontally to see the effect)

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.adjust {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="adjust" src="https://unsplash.it/2600/2600">
```

Comment: @Pe-Ter No problem. I'm glad you sorted the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may use **vh** and **vw** size property for your image(.descCoverFullscreen .fullscreenImageContainer img), vh stands for viewport height and vw stand for viewport width.

```css
.descCoverFullscreen {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
}

.descCoverFullscreen .fullscreenImageContainer {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.descCoverFullscreen .fullscreenImageContainer img {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
}

.descCoverFullscreen .fullscreenImageContainer button.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
}

.remove-icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    stroke: #fff !important;
    stroke-width: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="descCoverFullscreen">
  <div class="fullscreenImageContainer">
    <img src="http://hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/think-twice-code-once.jpg">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">
      <svg class="remove-icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <g transform="translate(0,-1036.3622)">
          <path d="m 2,1050.3622 12,-12"></path>
          <path d="m 2,1038.3622 12,12"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```